# Why doesn't the value change in Java

Tags: java

I just thought of this question: Using **Java**

```
int x = 1
int y = x;
x = 5;
```

why doesn't `y = 5` now?

Comment: Because java primitive type are immutable

Comment: You assign a value not a reference to `x`

Comment: beacause you only set y's value to the current x value, not it's memory pointer.

Comment: Not a bad question given that Java muddies this up when it comes to non-primitives. Not half as confusing as C# though.

Comment: Why would y be 5 after this code, according to you? If you can explain that, we can explain where you go wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @Bathsheba Why do you bring "primitives" into the picture? The code wouldn't work with reference types either. `String x = "1"; String y = x; x = "5";` -- exactly the same problem

Comment: Because in java primitive types hold only value.

Comment: Methinks this is a "before you've studied Java" question, so in that sense is language agnostic. Note that the C++ code `int x = 1; int y& = x; x = 5;` would set the value of `y` to 5 too. Also `java.lang.String` is a kludge since it messes around with essentially numeric operators.

Comment: @mustafacil In Java, reference type variables also only hold a value, the reference to the object. You cannot overload the assignment operator in Java like you can in other languages, so for the question of the OP it's irrelevant that `int` is a primitive type - exactly the same thing would have happened with a reference type.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt reference type holds a value of course but the value is a object's adress not like '5' or '10'. I mean that, a primitive's value is different from a reference's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int x = 1
int y = x;
x = 5;
```

primitive value is copied on this line `int y=x;` This is **not copy of reference** of an object which `x` is pointing to.

For reference :
http://javarevisited.blogspot.hk/2015/09/difference-between-primitive-and-reference-variable-java.html
[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @Savage - If u are okay with the answer, you can accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Because `y` is a separate variable to `x`, albeit initialised with the original value of `x`.

`y` is not a *reference* to `x`, or a reference to the same *object* as `x`. (`int` is a *primitive* type in Java).

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 1; //Some memory is initialized(say at location ox00001) and x is pointing to that

int y = x ; //Some memory is initialized(say at location ox00050) and value of x is copied to that memory 

x = 5 ; //value of memory location of x (i.e. ox00001) is changed to 5 but is not impacting memory location of y
```

But in case of Non-Primitive data type it shares memory location instead of data.
For reference http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/09/difference-between-primitive-and-reference-variable-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Take out two pieces of paper.

Write "x" on one, and "y" on the other.

Now write "1" on the paper you labelled "x". (`int x = 1;`)

Then take the number you see on the "x" paper and write that same number on the "y" paper. (`int y = x;`)

Then erase the number on the "x" paper and write "5" there instead. (`x = 5;`)

Observe that the number on the paper you labelled "y" did not change.
Variables work exactly like that.